# Calculating a Brute Force time

Tags: encryption, passwords, brute-force

Can anyone help me answering a sample exam question about cracking passwords.
I have been given the amount of checks per second, the maximum length of the password and how many potential characters makes up the password and I need to figure out how long it would take to crack the password?

`the attacker can perform 10^6 password checks every second;`

`the password is up to eight characters long;`

`each character from the password can consist of one of 70 different characters;`

How would you go about answering this question, what formula would you use to calculate the answer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are told the maximum length of a password and how many characters can appear in each position.  That will let you calculate how many different passwords there are of each length.  For example, there are 70 passwords of length 1, and 4900 passwords of length 2.  Overall, you can calculate the total number of possible passwords of all the allowed lengths.

Given that number, and the rate at which the attacker can check passwords, you are almost at the solution.  The piece of information you are missing is related to the probability of finding the right password over many attempts.  I will leave you to work that one out; you will learn more that way.